# Draw line between two Views in Android

Tags: android, android-canvas, draw, android-custom-view

I am trying to draw line between two Views in RelativeLayout but unable to do this.

```
    public class CustomRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    private Context mContext;
    private ImageButtonCustom[] imageButtonCustoms = new ImageButtonCustom[3];
    private Paint paint;
    CustomRelativeLayout customRelativeLayout;

    //private LineView lineView;
    public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        //setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        customRelativeLayout = this;
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStrokeWidth((float) 25);

        for(int x = 0 ; x < 3 ; x++){
            imageButtonCustoms[x] = new ImageButtonCustom(mContext,customRelativeLayout);
            imageButtonCustoms[x].setOnMoveListener(new ImageButtonCustom.OnMoveListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMove(Position positionXY) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);


        if(imageButtonCustoms[0] != null && imageButtonCustoms[1] != null)
            canvas.drawLine(imageButtonCustoms[0].getCenterX(),imageButtonCustoms[0].getCenterY()
        ,imageButtonCustoms[1].getCenterX(),imageButtonCustoms[1].getCenterY(),paint);

        if(imageButtonCustoms[1] != null && imageButtonCustoms[2] != null)
            canvas.drawLine(imageButtonCustoms[1].getCenterX(),imageButtonCustoms[1].getCenterY()
                    ,imageButtonCustoms[2].getCenterX(),imageButtonCustoms[2].getCenterY(),paint);

        if(imageButtonCustoms[0] != null && imageButtonCustoms[2] != null)
            canvas.drawLine(imageButtonCustoms[0].getCenterX(),imageButtonCustoms[0].getCenterY()
                    ,imageButtonCustoms[2].getCenterX(),imageButtonCustoms[2].getCenterY(),paint);


    }
}
```

Where **ImageButtonCustom**

```
   public class ImageButtonCustom extends ImageButton implements View.OnTouchListener{

    float dX, dY;

    private RelativeLayout rootView;
    private ImageButtonCustom imageButtonCustom;
    private OnMoveListener onMoveListener;

    public ImageButtonCustom(Context context,RelativeLayout rootView){
        super(context);
        this.rootView = rootView;
        init();

    }
    public ImageButtonCustom(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ImageButtonCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public ImageButtonCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        imageButtonCustom = this;
        setImageResource(R.drawable.bobo2);
        setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        setOnTouchListener(this);

        /*RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rl = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rl.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM);*/

        rootView.addView(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                dX = v.getX() - event.getRawX();
                dY = v.getY() - event.getRawY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                v.animate()
                        .x(event.getRawX() + dX)
                        .y(event.getRawY() + dY)
                        .setDuration(0)
                        .start();
                //no use of ViewPositionUtil
                onMoveListener.onMove(ViewPositionUtil.getXYPositionRelativeToRoot(imageButtonCustom));//positionXY);
                break;
        }
        rootView.invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    public void setOnMoveListener(OnMoveListener onMoveListener){
        this.onMoveListener = onMoveListener;
    }

    public float getCenterX(){
        return getX() + getWidth()  / 2;

    }
    public float getCenterY(){
        return getY() + getHeight() / 2;

    }

    public interface OnMoveListener{
        void onMove(Position positionXY);
    }
}
```

**Edit**

> I want to draw line between two views from their center which can be changed and reDraw when the view changes their position.

Comment: you could have used one more view in between the 2.. having background as line color, width 1 dp (line's thickness).

Comment: have you already debugged your onDraw()? Do getX() and getY() really contain the coordinates of the view?

Comment: @Jawad Zeb : Did you solve the problem. Please share.

Comment: I don't have access to the code now. but fixed

Comment: @Jawad Zeb: can i see the app where it is implemented?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=zerocode.eightballfree

Comment: @JawadZeb. Nice game thanks

Comment: @JawadZeb: I am unable to make up ViewPositionUtil.java. Any help?

Comment: Ask a question on stack but make sure to show your effort first otherwise no one will help you

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to know what Position is. Is it android core library or custom made class. Or is it related to import android.icu.text.Transliterator;?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208720/discussion-between-user1090751-and-jawad-zeb).

Answer (score 2):

If you want horizontal separation then

```xml
<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

If you want vertical separation then

```
<View
      android:id="@+id/view"
      android:layout_width="1dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

If you want separation in list view then you need to add to `<ListView />` tag

```
android:divider="5dp"
```

Comment: getListView().setDivider(null);
getListView().setDividerHeight(5);

Comment: I am generating view dynamically without xml.

Comment: so you can use above i comment. 
 getListView().setDiv‌​iderHeight(5); or you can use yourListView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));
yourListView.setDividerHeight(5);

Comment: I don't want to draw a line seperater between two Views. I want to draw line between two circle's center which are able to move over the screen .And as they move from one positon to another the line also move with them

Comment: Paint fgPaintSel = new Paint();
fgPaintSel.setARGB(255, 0, 0,0);
fgPaintSel.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
fgPaintSel.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] {10,20}, 0));

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103713/how-do-i-make-a-dotted-dashed-line-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Saw in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049852/android-drawing-separator-divider-line-in-layout) response, adding a new `View` between the `RelativeLayout` with height 1dp should enough:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

Hope it helps!,

Answer (score 0):

You could use this!

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:text="FaceBook Feeds" />

         <View
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="2dp"
             android:background="#d13033"/><!-- this is line -->

         <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list1"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the real problem here is that your onDraw() method is not calling. Add this in your constructor. For reference see this: [Own defined Layout , onDraw() method not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781892/own-defined-layout-ondraw-method-not-getting-called)

```
this.setWillNotDraw(false);
```