# Videos list auto-play when scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm developing an app which show a list of contents to users. The contents list is made of images and videos. I'd like to make the videos in the list auto-play when user scroll to it, and stop when it's no longer visible. Just like the [Vine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.vine.android) and [Facebook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana) app.

I've search for some tutorial and found none. Please help me to build it, do you have any tutorial or ref link or any 3rd which support this?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4219583/5164938

This is an answer to a question that is almost exactly like yours. Try some of the other answers in that thread as well, and let me know if any of them work for you.